# How to change current element value in table on click?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to inline edit of current `td` value. For example suppose I have 3 rows in my table and I would like to edit 2 row so when I click on second `td` edit link then editable textbox will show at current name column and allow to edit.

Following is my code:

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </thead>

    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit_agent" id="edit_agent">Edit</a></td>
        <td id="log_name" class=='log_name' contenteditable="true" data-old_value ="<?php echo $value->name; ?>" ><?php echo $f_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $city; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
    <tr>

</table>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(".edit_agent").click(function(){

    var oldVal = jQuery('.log_name').attr('data-old_value');
    var $input = jQuery('<input>', {
        value: oldVal,
        type: 'text',
        blur: function() {
            jQuery(this).oldVal
        },
        keyup: function(e) {
            if (e.which === 13) $input.blur();
        }
    }).appendTo( jQuery(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(3)') ).focus();

    return false;
});
```

I have tried above code but not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I see double equal to with class: class=='log_name'

Try changing this to

```
class="log_name"
```

Comment: I tried but when i click another td then old one textbox not hide